# State changes during useFocus cleanup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I wish to post to a database changes to array of object (these can be added or removed very quicly) and I don't want to access the database very time the array is changed (to avoid doing too many request in such a short amount of time). For this I would like to "Save" these changes once the user [changes screens in React Native](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect#). My only problem occurs when accessing my state during useEffects' [clean up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup), during the removal handler my state changes as expected, but when the clean up is triggered the state pretty much goes back to it's initial state (which is set with useEffect).

```
export const ProfileView = () => {
  const [userTags, setUserTags] = useState < EnumTags > profileData.tags;
  // TODO: Avoid data from being saved and fetched everytime a tag is removed

  useFocusEffect(
    // Fetch Tag Data
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // *** Grab data from a JS object ***

      console.log("----------------");
      console.log("Tag data fetched");
      console.log("----------------");

      const tagData = [...profileData.tags];
      setUserTags(tagData);

      // *** EXPECTED LOG: 5 ***
      // *** OUTPUT IS: 5 ***
      console.log("- Before: ", userTags.length);

      return () => {
        // Save changes
        // *** DURING CLEAN UP, SAVE DATA IN THE JS OBJECT
        console.log("----------------");
        console.log("Save changes");
        console.log("----------------");

        // *** EXPECTED OUTPUT IF A ELEMENT IS REMOVED: NOT 5 ***
        // *** OUTPUT: 5, same has initial state
        console.log("~ Tags: ", userTags.length);
        // *** ATTEMPT TO SAVE DATA
        profileData.tags = [...userTags];
        console.log("- After: ", profileData.tags.length);
      };
    }, [])
  );

  const handdleTagRemoval = (tagName: string) => {
    // *** REMOVE SELECTED ITEM, DONE USING ARRAY.FILTER
    console.log("Remove tag");

    const tags = [...userTags];
    const filteredTags = tags.filter((tagItem) => tagItem.name !== tagName);
    // profileData.tags = filteredTags;
    setUserTags(filteredTags);
    console.log("~", tagName, " was removed");
    console.log(userTags.length, " are left");
  };
};
```

Comment: Empty dependency array encloses initial component state when the component mounts. Need to add `userTags` to the dependency to update the memoized callback. Also, `useCallback` doesn't return a cleanup function. Did you intend to really use `useEffect` instead?

Comment: I'm doing this based on [useFocus](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) which apparently is React Navigation's equivalent to useEffect. Maybe I should update the tittle, I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Solved as suggested by [@Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) by adding `userTags` as a dependency. This means I am using this hook two extra times.

```
 useFocusEffect(
    // Fetch Tag Data
    React.useCallback(() => {
      console.log("----------------");
      console.log("Tag data fetched");
      console.log("----------------");
      const tagData = [...profileData.tags];
      setUserTags(tagData);
      console.log("- Before: ", userTags.length);
    }, [])
  );

  useFocusEffect(
    // Save changes
    React.useCallback(() => {
      console.log("----------------");
      console.log("Save changes");
      console.log("----------------");
      console.log("~ Tags: ", userTags.length);
    }, [userTags])
  );

  useFocusEffect(
    // Post final changes
    React.useCallback(() => {
      return () => {
        // Save Final changes
        console.log("----------------");
        console.log("Post changes");
        console.log("----------------");
        console.log("~ Post Tags: ", userTags.length);
        profileData.tags = [...userTags];
        console.log("- After: ", profileData.tags.length);
      };
    }, [userTags])
  );
```